# Como se resuelve el caso de cmap = cm.get_cmap('gnuplot')?

Tags: matplotlib

## plotting a scatter matrix

```
from matplotlib import cm 

X = fruits[['height', 'width', 'mass', 'color_score']]

y = fruits['fruit_label']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

cmap = cm.get_cmap('gnuplot')

scatter = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(X_train, c= y_train, marker = 'o', s=40, hist_kwds={'bins':15}, figsize=(9,9), cmap=cmap)
```

ese codigo arroja lo siguiente:

MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The get_cmap function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.7 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use `matplotlib.colormaps[name]` or `matplotlib.colormaps.get_cmap(obj)` instead.
cmap = cm.get_cmap('gnuplot')

Estoy usando Google Colab (Version matplotlib: 3.7.1 , Pandas:  1.5.3 ). Intente hacer lo que me dice el warning sin exito, soy nuevo en esto.

Alguien sabe como se resuelve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas noches a todos.

Acabo de solucionar usando el siguiente codigo al principio de la celda:

```
%matplotlib inline
plt.close('all')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas cambiar la forma en la que importas y llamas a la función, por ejemplo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmap = plt.colormaps.get_cmap('gnuplot')
```